# Publishing arrays with rqt_publisher in ROS2

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, rqt

If I put in the field `array('f', [0.0, 0.0]), I get this:

```
[ERROR] [1706215862.940833343] [get_message_class]: Malformed message_type: sequence<float>
Python eval failed for expression "array('f', [0.0, 0.0])" with an exception "name 'array' is not defined"
Publisher._evaluate_expression(): failed to evaluate expression: "array('f', [0.0, 0.0])" as Python type "None"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rqt_publisher/publisher.py", line 161, in change_publisher
    new_text = handler(self._publishers[publisher_id], topic_name, new_value)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rqt_publisher/publisher.py", line 262, in _change_publisher_expression
    expression, error_prefix, slot_type.__name__)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'. Did you mean: '__ne__'?
```

[image: RQT Publisher]